# MCP23008 I2C bus device address by "i2cdetect -y 1" is not stable

Tags: gpio, i2c, raspberry-pi-os

When I connect the GPIO expander MCP23008 to the raspberry pi 1 model B+ via I2C, the address of the MCP23008 on the raspberry pi keeps switching between 0x20 and 0x21, and sometimes it's not even detected (see the captions below). What's wrong? How can I stop this uncontrollable change of address on the I2C?
The OS is the latest raspberry pi OS desktop version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the circuit:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have not wired the device correctly.  If you want a solution we need to see your wiring.

Comment: @joan I added the circuit diagram to my question.

Comment: @S.E.K, Ah, you need to tie the hardware address pins to either High or Low. You cannot leave them floating, which usually means High, but not for this chip. One of the manufacturer's design bug for this chip is that floating means indeterminate. This is the MCP23008/017 newbie's sorrow. Another bug is a restriction on the use of one or more of the GPIO pins.

Comment: @tlfong01 - looks like pins 3, 4 and 5 are grounded though - according to the diagram - but who knows what is actually connected where, that image of the actual connections is next to useless

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Ah yes, you are right, the address pins seems correctly connected. Let me suggest some troubleshooting tips to SEK later.

Comment: @S.E.K. I usually do the following: (1) Use a multi-meter to do point to point "open short" testing, to make sure if all the point to point connections are shorted, the neighboring pins supposed to be disconnected are open. (2) Change the address pin connections from G, G, G to G G Vcc and other connection patterns to see if "i2cdetect -y 1 (or 0, I forgot) shows expected hex addresses. (3) Swap another mcp23008 (Yes, I usually have more than one for swap testing. / to continue, ...

Comment: since the address is flipping between 20 and 21 it's likely to be the A0 address line that isn't grounded properly - that's pin 5

Comment: (4) The bread board sockets might be loosen, causing "poor electrical contact", so why not move to another position, use another set of jumper wires (sometimes the jumper wires, after being bent too often, broken inside, and cause intermittent "break and make" connections. (5) So you see, what I am doing is ***SWAP, SWAP, SWAP*** - swap and test anything you can swap and test. (6)  Other things EE pros do but newbies won't bother to do are "BACKUP, BACKUP, BACKUP" and "DOCUMENT, DOCUMENT, DOCUMENT", / to continue, ...

Comment: @Jaromanda X, yes, swapping only the pin 5 related wiring/connection is so called "clever swap", done after thinking and narrowing down the possible trouble making area, opposed to "blind swap" of swapping everything without thinking, of course wasting time.

Comment: I remember when I first learned mcp23x/08/17, I actually started with mcp23s08, then swapped to mcp23008, then swapped to s17, then 017. Then I swapped from through hole chips to modules.

Comment: We need a clear photo of the connections.  The photo is not good enough.

Comment: @joan I've just updated the photo of the connections, hope this one's clearer...

Comment: Better, but it still doesn't let us be sure.  The connections appear correct.  You appear to have all the address lines pulled to ground.  An overhead view as well would be useful.

Comment: @S.E.K. (1) I would like to confirm one thing: ***Have you powered MCP23008 with 3V3, NOT 5V0?*** (2) I googled a schematic and my old posts to refresh my memory.  Then I remembered that I always use a logical level converter to convert Rpi's 3V3 signals to 5V. If you are following my photos to use 5V Vcc, without a TSX0102/4 converter, you might (a) Get I/O errors (i2cdetect -y 1 does snot show I/O errors, python does), (b) Damage Rpi. (3) References: 
[1] MCP23017 Inputs/Output copy - EasyEda 2018-08-26
https://easyeda.com/mankes/i2c-expander. /to continue, ...

Comment: [2] Rpi.Org.Forum mcp23008 tlfong01 Search found 11 matches:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=mcp23008+tlfong01

[3] Rpi.Org.Forum mcp23017 tlfong01 Search found 178 matches: 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=mcp23017+tlfong01&sid=d21077b32e1eb0144ff7742ea88457c3

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for all these suggestions. I made sure to connect mcp23008 to the 5V Pin not the 3.3V pin of the pi. I have a low voltage issue with my raspberry pi ("Low voltage warning, Please check your power supply"). I changed the charger but the problem persists. Maybe not enough voltage is coming to the mcp23008. How can I debug that using a multimeter?

Comment: You need to correctly wire the A0, A1 & A2 pins to +5V or GND and don't let them float.

Comment: @S.E.K. There seems to be some confusion. I mean ***you MUST power MCP23008 with 3V3!***

Comment: @tlfong01 I connected it to 3.3V and then changed to 5V, but I didn't notice any change in the behavior of the MCP23008. I checked the component's datasheet as well to see if there's a mention of the required voltage, but didn't find any particular mention of 3.3V. How do you know that MCP23008 should be connected to a 3.3V?

Comment: Ah, yes you can power MCP23017/S17 from 1.8V to 5.5V. It is not the you should not power 5V for the operation and safety reasons. It is for the health of the Rpi which is a 3V3 device with 3V3 logic. In other words, Rpi talks "softly" at 3V3, but if MCP talks loudly at 5V0, the HIgh and Low margins might mismatch and signals would lose in translation. One other big problem is that if Rpi's input mode GPIO pin is tying, through a pull up resistor, to 5V, the GPIO pin might get "***latched up***" which would fry the Rpi from 30 minutes to uncertaIn time. Anyway, Rpi's life might be shortened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's comments I've come to a solution. All comes down to not letting the wires float (as suggested by @Dougie). Connecting the wires in a breadboard does not guarantee that they be actually connected, so I soldered them, and that stabilized the address of the MCP23008 on the I2C bus.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pullup resistors on the I2C lines? I'd put a 10K resistor between the SCL/SDA lines and VCC

Comment: The Pi has hardwired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 on SDA and SCL.  No more should be needed.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic and a little late, but a few things that may generally help when dealing with high impedance/fast changing inputs/protocols; and this device in particular, having recently been developing with the MCP23008.

- As mentioned, don't let inputs float; tie them high (preferably) or low. often the pull-ups provided via software are insufficient at (often) about 100K - 10K is usually fine.
- Try to keep connecting wires short
- remember that I2C was developed as a short-range communication protocol
- Power supplies should be clean, try adding a 10, 22, or 100uF electrolytic, together with a 0.1uf cap across the supply on your development board/breadboard. Ensure that the PSU does not violate the device’s min/max requirements and that you can supply enough current
- Add a 0.1uF capacitor to chips across their supply pins (as close as possible) - **I have found that the GPIO register, 0x09 on this chip occasionally reports nonsense without such decupling.** (being lazy will bite you! :D ). During setup for this device, I set the first 9 registers as required, and read them back for confirmation. This way we know that the chip is communicating/I2C is up/the chip exists!
- Understand (as you have discovered) that breadboards are nasty things when it comes to noise, contact resistance, stray capacitance etc.
- understand the susceptibility of devices to damage from static charges. Take the manufacturers precautions!
- Most importantly read and understand the datasheet (and make sure
  that you read the actual manufacturers datasheet, not a generic
  one!). Almost without exception, EVERYTHING you need to know will be
  in there! Manufacturers want you to use their chips and so they give
  you every chance to make them work.